# Filter multi-dimensional array by specific key and create sub array PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have below array I want to group by course id and course type (fulltime and parttime)

```
$enablefulltype = 1;
$enableparttime = 1;
     foreach ($courses as $c){
                    $f = new stdClass();
                    $f->course_id = $c->course;
                    $f->form =  $c->id;
                    $f->module = $c->module;
                    $f->type = $c->type; [ex: fulltime, parttime]
                    $f->posts = [];     
                    $results[] = $f;
    
                }
```

How can I filter above array as below structre. pls advice

```
 [course_id ] {
        fulltime : [
                       $f->form =  $c->id;
                    $f->module = $c->module;
                    $f->type = $c->type; [ex: fulltime, parttime]
                    $f->posts = [];
            ]
    parttime : []
    }
```

Comment: What is your issue in this code?

Comment: @JeanGotopo I want to find way to filter my array to courses id and course type filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the multi-dimensional array you want. If you don't want to lose those `unset` variables comment out that line. It's just there because you didn't record them in your sample.

```
foreach($courses as $c) {
  $c->posts = [];
  $c->form = $c->id ;
  $c->course_id = $c->course;
  unset($c->id, $c->course, $c->id);
  $results[$c->course_id][$c->type][] = $c;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't support if courses array is having multiple records for same course ids

Comment: Just updated answer. For each `course id`, you will get `type` and in each `type` you'll get an array of courses.

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67959431/how-to-filter-an-array-based-on-mutliple-conditions-php too pls