# How to filter an array based on mutliple conditions PHP

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have below array and I want to change the outout based on some conditions

```
   foreach($courses as $c) {
$c->type == "fulltime" ? 'full' : 'part';
                    $f = new stdClass();
                    $f->course_id = $c->course;
                    $f->form =  $c->id;
                    $f->module = $c->module;
                    $f->unread = $unreadcount;
                    $f->type = $c->type;
                    $f->posts = $posts;   
                
                 $results[$c->course_id][$c->type][] = $f;
    }
```

current structure:

```
 [course_id]{
       full : [
                       $f->form =  $c->id;
                    $f->module = $c->module;
                    $f->type = $c->type; [ex: fulltime, parttime]
                  
            ]
    part : []
    posts : []
    }
```

Conditions :

`if ($enableFulltimeCourse =1 && $unreadcount >0)` -> show full[]  and part[] else its empty
`if ($enableParttimeCourse =1 && $f->type == "part")` -> show part[] else its empty

What i tried

```
if ($enableFulltimeCourse =1 && $unreadcount >0){
                    unset($f);
                }
                $results[$forum->course][$forum->type][] = $f;
```

please advice

Comment: can you explain little bit more

Comment: @Jerson  $courses data is having results of fulltime and partime courses and unread items based on course type. via my front end im getting values and I need to prepare the array based on those conditions. 
Ex: $enableFulltimeCourse is having a value and unread iteams are not 0 then I want to show sub arrays of full time items and posts. other wise those sub arrays should empty. I tried with unset($f) based on conditions but it didn't works.

Comment: @NicoHaase if ($enableFulltimeCourse =1 && $unreadcount >0) {  unset($f);} I tried like this but it didnt works. it return null for each item.

Comment: Why do you use `unset`  for that? Why not use `array_filter`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `==` or `===` for comparison. Also, not sure what you meant by *show X else it's empty*, but here's how to form your conditional. I don't think you meant `unset($f);` - as that would delete your whole object.

```
if ($enableFulltimeCourse == 1)
  if ($unreadcount >0){
    // show full[] and part[] else its empty
    foreach($f->full as $item) {
       // loop through the full
    }

    foreach($f->part as $item) {
       // loop through the part
    }
  } else if ($f->type == "part") {
    unset($f->full); //show part[] else its empty
    foreach($f->part as $item) {
       // loop through the part
    }
  }
}
$results[$forum->course][$forum->type][] = $f;
```

Comment: @dilzdilz - - Did this help solve your question? If so, please accept as the answer. thanks